# عامين masculine sound plural in Qur'an

Tags: quran, arabic

Could عالمين actually mean, since it is pluralized using masculine sound plural "just inhabitants of the world", not the usual translation 'the whole universe'? Otherwise, why is it used?

Comment: In the context of which verse?

Comment: any verse where the plural is formed using the جَمْع سالِم

Comment: I don't know of any verse quoting عالمون as it basically sounds wrong, but there are plenty quoting عالمين the plural of عالَم is عوالم and maybe أعلام!

Comment: Actually it's genitive العالمين is the one appearing; In fuSha عوامل

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Arabic language and has no relation to the Qur'an nor Islam, the attribution simply is wrong!

Comment: Relevant meta posts https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/should-we-allow-questions-regarding-the-arabic-language and https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1311/arabic-stackexchange-re-proposed

Comment: @Sassir Thanks for the info. If there were an Arabic beta this question could, as a last resort, be moved to it; unfortunately, I do not think it possible for it to arouse the same interest again

Answer (score 1):

First of all this is rather a question on Arabic language as both عالَمُون or عالِمون are not used or present (in this form) in the Qur'an at all. As they sound somewhat wrong, at least they are not much used instead of the other options (especially in the first case)!

According to [al-maany](https://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-ar/%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%88%D9%86/)
عالَمُون is one plural form of عالَم: which means world, creation and some even add any thing in the universe.

while 
عالِمون is one plural form of [عالِم](https://www.almaany.com/en/dict/ar-en/%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%90%D9%85/): scientist, scholar etc.

Comment: عالمين, which is اسم مفرور, appears 77 times in Qur'an, as soon as in 1:2:4 http://corpus.quran.com/search.jsp?q=%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%8A%D9%86 or http://haqeeqat.pk/English%20Tafsir%20e%20Haqeeqat/00.%20Individual%20Ayaat/001.%20Al%20Fateha/001.2-4.htm

Comment: https://www.almaany.com/quran/1/2/4/

Comment: Should I infer that عالمين and عالمون are not related?

Comment: @GJC I guess your question is answered or am I wrong?

Comment: I am afraid it isn't; so far, the discussion has been a bit childish and about grammar and literalness

Comment: @GJC you are asking a question which belongs to a language site not to Islam SE, you tried your best to squeeze it to make it fit by adding tags... you have changed your whole question now so it seems for it is best to delete my answer and vote to close as we had a similar discussion on meta https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3099/what-are-the-rules-on-editing-questions-into-completely-new-questions-for-islam before